# Office 365 compatibility issue with Office Standard 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using office 365. I have one excel file from Office 2010 standard. When I open this file protected view messages shown. After enabling editing some of the data got lost and cells filled with "#####". This event also disabled column/Row re-size. While this file is working fine with office 2010 standard.

Screen-1:

[image]

Screen-2:

[image]

Comment: So, if you click "Enable Editing", then you can't resize colums?

Comment: Yes. Also we get result as shown in "Screen-2"

Comment: Also file extension should be .xlsx for best compatibility with Office 365.

Comment: Yes, file extension is .xlsx.

Comment: If you have the source file (from Office 2010) upload to cloud (Google Drive or something similar) and try to open it online. This gives you the opportunity to recover some data from your original file.

Comment: Are these cells populated with formula's or with data? Has the formatting changed? Have you checked the formatting of each cell? It looks like that could be an issue. If the data is a number but then formatted as a date the protected view might show you the actual content (original number) while the unprotected view could convert this to a "long date" which is too long for the cell to show, hence why you get ###.
Just a few ideas.

Comment: I am also IT person. I have already done such types of experiments. I also made some chats with Microsoft experts. But they are suggesting me to work with "office 2010 standard" only.